# Run a block of Script after every img element on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I run a WordPress blog. I want that for every `<img />` tag on a single post page, I will have a script placed directly after it as though I was using the `::after` in CSS.

I know for CSS I could do the below to display "**read more**" after all my `<img/>` tags

```css
img::before {
  content: "read more -";
}
```

But in my case "**read more**" is a script, an advertisement script specifically.

How do get my script code to display after all images on my webpages?

Comment: You can't (or at least shouldn't be able to) use CSS to inject JS into a page. If you have control of the webpages, you could just use normal JS to accomplish this?

Comment: Actually you **can't** use `img::before`...as images can't have pseudo-elements.

Comment: how is that done?

Comment: A script can affect an entire page. Why do you need the script _directly next to_ an image? What is your actual goal?

Comment: to display run/display an script beneath all images on the webpge, without me pasting the script individually after every image

Comment: I don't think you're using the word script correctly. Do you mean you want to execute code for each image? It seems like that because you mentioned using `::after`. I doubt you'd want to directly paste a script after each image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to execute code for each image, use a selector. Obviously, this can be narrowed down to what element you specifically want to target:

```js
var imgs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'))

imgs.forEach((img, i) => {
  // Code here
  img.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div>Test ' + i + '</div>')
})
```

```html
<img src="" alt="img1" />
<img src="" alt="img2" />
<img src="" alt="img3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a single script.

In the script you will use a selector to target all the images you wish to target.

If you want to select literally every single image on the page, you can use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

If you want to select every image which has a specific class, you can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my-image');
```

If  you want to select every image which appears in a certain context, you can use something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.post img');
```

etc.